# How do I close a mesh without losing the hole I made>

Tags: mesh

I had to make a cutout in my mesh for 4 holes that I wanted to introduce. I want to make the mesh watertight, but because I had to cut through surfaces, it is showing the 'inside' of my mesh. How can I make this file printable without losing the holes I created?

[image: red is the gap between the two surfaces, ideally where I would introduce a new face or something to close the mesh]

red is the gap between the two surfaces, ideally where I would introduce a new face or something to close the mesh

Comment: you  can try bridge edge loops

Comment: @susu I tried but theres so many vertices it is sort of a mess